# Tabulation added to returned ajax call data

Tags: ajax

my problem is that whenever I do an ajax call and console.log the returned data, there is a tabulation in front of my returned data. Is this normal? If so, is there a way to strip the tabulation from the data variable? My code is below.

```
function search_rhymes_get_rhyme_content() {
    echo 'Test';

    die();
}

$.ajax( {
    url: rhymes_ajax_obj.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        'action': 'search_rhymes_get_rhyme_content'
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( 'Test:' + data );  
    },
    error: function( error ) {
        console.log( error );
    }
} );
```

Thanks

Comment: What is a tabulation? Can you post an example of the output

Comment: Output : https://ibb.co/Jcb0WH6
I think it's called a tab in english (tab key, above caps lock on keyboard).

Comment: You can use trim to get to get rid of that `data.trim()`.  Whitespaces in your output usually means that your <?php tag has spaces before it.

Comment: It works, thank you! I want to answer my question with the solution, but I'm stuggling to display code. I don't know how I did it the first time.

Comment: Paste the code in the textbox select it then press Ctrl+K

Comment: Ok, I posted the solution. Is there a way to "thumb up" your solution? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Output: https://ibb.co/QQHGgXV

I added the following line before my console.log:

```
data = data.trim();
```

Here's the updated code with the solution:

```
function search_rhymes_get_rhyme_content() {
    echo 'Test';

    die();
}

$.ajax( {
    url: rhymes_ajax_obj.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        'action': 'search_rhymes_get_rhyme_content'
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( 'Test1:' + data );

        data = data.trim();

        console.log( 'Test2:' + data );
    },
    error: function( error ) {
        console.log( error );
    }
} );
```